# Load JSON into boost variables_map

Tags: json, boost

I would like JSON:

```
"section" : {
    "subsection" : {
        "value" : 33,
        "add" : "somestring"
    },
    "subparam" : "hello world"
}
```

to be represented as following boost::program_options::variables_map:

```
"section.subsection.value" = "33"
"section.subsection.add" = "somestring"
"section.subparam" = "hello world"
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Now i recursively traverse JSON tree and concatenate keys into "key.key.key...." adding such strings into variables_map, but is there easier way to do this?

Comment: that fact is not important :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
var o1 = {
  "section" : {
    "subsection" : {
        "value" : 33,
        "add" : "somestring"
    },
    subparam : "hello world"
   }
};

var o2 = (function walk(o, path, acc) {
  acc = acc || {};
  for (var name in o) {
    var pd = (path ? path+'.' : '')+name, od = o[name];
    if (typeof od === "object") {
       walk(od, pd, acc);
    } else {
      acc[path+'.'+name] = od.toString();
    }
  }
  return acc;
})(o1);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/efocel/2/edit) (hit "Run with JS" and open the console)

This assumes you don't start with some JSON but with a JavaScript object. If you really start with json, use `o1 = JSON.parse(yourJSON);`.

**EDIT :** I now get from your tags you probably doesn't want to use javascript. Then I let you or another user port it using boost. I let my answer in case it's useful.